# "Like happened" vs "like it happened"

Tags: grammaticality

> Like happened right after you got a job, I too am going to be swamped with work.

> Like **it** happened right after you got a job, I too am going to swamped with work.

Do both sentences mean the same thing and are grammatically correct?

Comment: _Like happened_ doesn't sound right; I would prefer _as happened_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These might be technically correct but a native speaker would rarely formulate them as such. The best alternative is to my ear is:

> As happened right after you got a job, I'm swamped with work.